# Solution Not Building in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Whenever I build any solution in visual studio the build skips every change I've made. I've checked the build log and every time I request a build the log just outputs:

*0 of 257 functions ( 0.0%) were compiled, the rest were copied from previous compilation.*

It does this regardless of the changes I make, does anyone know what is happening?

Comment: Did you try "Rebuild" action instead of "Build"?

Comment: While that does work I'm still wondering why build doesn't

Comment: So, it is still not compiling changes after Rebuild? Do you modify cpp files or some other files? If so, maybe close VS, delete all build directories (Debug/Release etc.) in solution and subprojects and restart VS.

Comment: It compiles changes after a rebuild just not after a regular build, and the only changes I have made are to the files I created, I haven't changed any default settings.

Comment: I mean, does Build still work incorrectly after you did Rebuild? Do you edit .cpp files or some other files? Are these files displayed in the solution view?

Comment: Yeah even after rebuild build still doesn't work, but the only .cpp files I have edited are my own. should I try to delete the build directory like you described before?